# Search mangle into libraries

Tags: bash, grep, nm

I want to find some functions or structures into library files. For this purpose I'm using "nm" command using "find" command output as parameter files. (I want search in /usr/lib directory recursively) I tried with this command without success:

```
nm -A | find /usr/lib -name "*.a" | grep "FunctionThatIWantFound"
```

Comment: `find` doesn't read anything from standard input so it's not really clear what you expect this to accomplish. You want to run `nm -A` on the files reported by `find`? Or the output from `nm -A` should somehow be used by `find`?

Comment: My intention was get find output as parameter

Comment: That doesn't really clarify the question. Your answer runs `nm` on the files reported by `find` so if that's what you actually want, I guess we are done here; I'm mainly pointing out that your question is very unclear, and that we might be able to help clear up some misunderstandings if you could [edit] it to explain your thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution

```
nm -A $(find /usr/lib -name "*.a")| grep "fprintf"
```

or

```
find /usr/lib -name '*.a' -exec nm -A {} +| grep "fprintf"
```

thanks to [@tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee)

Comment: As a minor robustness tweak, `find /usr/lib -name '*.a' -exec nm -A {} +` avoids choking on nontrivial file names or too much output from `find`.  The `-exec ... +` option might not be available in your `find`, though; as a fallback, `-exec ... \;` should work all the way back to the dark ages, but spawn more processes and hence run slower.